# NSInternalInconsistencyException - on AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

My application is crashing with a very weird error message.

The error message is

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboard nibForViewControllerWithIdentifier:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIStoryboard.m:115
2013-05-06 19:07:04.543 SocialApp[2427:c07] GoogleAnalytics 2.0b3 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:41): Uncaught exception: Invalid parameter not satisfying: [identifier length] > 0
2013-05-06 19:07:09.586 SocialApp[2427:c07] 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [identifier length] > 0'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x317e012 0x2c73e7e 0x317de78 0x2817f35 0x19522ba 0x19523d9 0x37f78 0x15ec817 0x15ec882 0x153ba25 0x153bdbf 0x153bf55 0x1544f67 0x355a4 0x15087b7 0x1508da7 0x1509fab 0x151b315 0x151c24b 0x150dcf8 0x385bdf9 0x385bad0 0x30f3bf5 0x30f3962 0x3124bb6 0x3123f44 0x3123e1b 0x15097da 0x150b65c 0x334d 0x3275)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

The app was initially crashing at the line

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:googleAnalyticsKey];
```

but after I commented out the line, it is now crashing at

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The error message is the same. I have been trying to fix it all day but no solution.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    commonClassInstance = [[Common alloc] init];
    configFileDictionary = [commonClassInstance returnConfigFileDictionary];
    resourceFileDictionary = [commonClassInstance returnResourceFileDictionary];

    //NSString *googleAnalyticsKey = [[configFileDictionary valueForKey:@"Keys"] valueForKey:@"GoogleAnalyticsKey"];

    // Instance to track Uncaught Exception
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

    // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;

    // Create tracker instance.
   // id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:googleAnalyticsKey];
//#pragma unused(tracker)

    sleep(3);

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window addSubview:newsViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:blogViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:careerViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:videoViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:photosViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:contactViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:stocksViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:executiveViewController.view];
    [window addSubview:companyInfoViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is this a released app that just started crashing? Does it crash for everyone or just one user?

Comment: `    sleep(3);`  .... uh ... wut?  That ain't right.   Not your problem, but that is a sure sign of code gone wrong.

Comment: Why are you adding so many views? Are you showing all these views at once?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `googleAnalyticsKey` is non-nil and has a valid value.

Beyond that, your question doesn't have enough clues.   Post the backtrace of the actual crash.